# Get date from milliseconds

Tags: javascript, date

I've been trying this for the past 12 hours but I still don't get it. I have a value that is milliseconds from `1/1`, and I want to get the date and time from this millisecond. For example, if I have `0`, I want to get `1/1/2014 00:00:00:000` and if I have `31,536,000,000` I want to get `12/31/2014 23:59:59:999`. I want the same in anything in between. Here's my code so far:

```
milliseconds = 31532123456
var janfirst = new Date('1/1/2014').getTime()
thedate = milliseconds + janfirst
```

but I know this won't give me the dates (month, day, and time). How would I do this? Sorry for asking similar questions in a row. I'm really bad with dates in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = new Date(1416157734401);

var day = [
    date.getDate(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join('/')

var time = [
  date.getHours(),
  date.getMinutes(),
  date.getSeconds(),
  date.getMilliseconds()
].join(':')

console.log(day + ' ' + time)
```

There is very good library [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
moment(1416157734401).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss:ms")
```

Answer (score 1):

This works: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/snuggles08/2rrw6kz5/1/).

What you do is use `new Date(thedate)` to make the new date.

Comment: *How* exactly is my answer worse? The other answer gives incorrect information *and* advertises.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's significantly worse, but it's certainly not better. The other answer has slightly more detail, and suggests a library to make working with dates easier. I wouldn't call it advertising, rather a suggestion.

Comment: @DaveNewton How is it more detailed? I see less detail.

Comment: That's bizarre, but ok.